# Joining two incomplete data.tables with the same column names

Tags: r, data.table

I have two incomplete data.tables with the same column names.

```
dt1 <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3), v1 = c("w", "x", NA), v2 = c("a", NA, "c"))
dt2 <- data.table(id = c(2, 3, 4), v1 = c(NA, "y", "z"), v2 = c("b", "c", NA))
```

They look like this:

```
dt1
   id   v1   v2
1:  1    w    a
2:  2    x <NA>
3:  3 <NA>    c
```

```
> dt2
   id   v1   v2
1:  2 <NA>    b
2:  3    y    c
3:  4    z <NA>
```

Is there a way to merge the two by filling in the missing info?

This is the result I'm after:

```
   id v1   v2
1:  1  w    a
2:  2  x    b
3:  3  y    c
4:  4  z <NA>
```

I've tried various data.table joins, merges but I either get the columns repeated:

```
> merge(dt1,
+       dt2,
+       by = "id",
+       all = TRUE)

   id v1.x v2.x v1.y v2.y
1:  1    w    a <NA> <NA>
2:  2    x <NA> <NA>    b
3:  3 <NA>    c    y    c
4:  4 <NA> <NA>    z <NA>
```

or the rows repeated:

```
> merge(dt1,
+       dt2,
+       by = names(dt1),
+       all = TRUE)
   id   v1   v2
1:  1    w    a
2:  2 <NA>    b
3:  2    x <NA>
4:  3 <NA>    c
5:  3    y    c
6:  4    z <NA>
```

Both data.tables have the same column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by ID and get the unique values after omitting NAs, i.e.

```
library(data.table)

merge(dt1, dt2, all = TRUE)[, 
        lapply(.SD, function(i)na.omit(unique(i))), 
                            by = id][]

#   id v1   v2
#1:  1  w    a
#2:  2  x    b
#3:  3  y    c
#4:  4  z <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also start out with rbind():

```
rbind(dt1, dt2)[, lapply(.SD, \(x) unique(x[!is.na(x)])), by = id]

#       id     v1     v2
#    <num> <char> <char>
# 1:     1      w      a
# 2:     2      x      b
# 3:     3      y      c
# 4:     4      z   <NA>
```

Comment: What does the \ mean?

Comment: `\(x)` is short for `function(x)` in newer version of R.

Answer (score 0):

First `full_join` and after that `group_by` per id and merge the rows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt1 %>%
  full_join(dt2, by = c("id", "v1", "v2")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(starts_with('v'), .direction = 'updown') %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     id v1    v2   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 w     a    
2     2 x     b    
3     3 y     c    
4     4 z     NA
```

Comment: This is one of many examples I've seen lately where tidyverse is between you and the code.